# Slowly dimming LED-s

Tags: led, astable

I was wondering if it is possible to make LED-s in an astable multivibrator slowly get brighter then slowly dimmer.
Can somebody help me please?
Thank you for your kindness! Have a good day!

Comment: Yes and no. You need two oscillators. One ramping up and down at the dimming rate. The second to do the PWM (pulse-width modulation) where the pulse widths are set by the output of the first oscillator.

Comment: How slow?  10 ms, 1 sec, 100 sec?  You could run the led from a voltage to current source and have an RC decay on the turn on and off voltage.

Comment: Depending on timing, etc, there are several ways to do this. You could generate a ramp up and down to set the demand and this could then feed either a constant current or a PWM circuit to control LED current. Depending on how many I had to make and timing however, I may seriously be considering a micro controller.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhfFzs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Triangular PWM generator.*

As discussed in the comments, to do what you ask you need a triangle generator to generate the dimming control signal and you need a PWM generator to be controlled by the triangle generator.

The circuit of Figure 1 is intended to get you started but leaves some calculations for you to do.

**How it works**

***Half-supply reference***

- The circuit works on a single supply voltage. The op-amps need to work about the centre-point of this supply so we generate a half-supply voltage using a voltage divider and capacitor.

***Squarewave generator***

This works in conjunction with the triangle generator as follows.

- OA1 is configured as a Schmitt trigger. If the output is high the '+' input is pulled high by R3. This will keep the output high until the '+' input is pulled low enough by R5. (We'll come back to this.)
- When it does switch low the process repeats but in the opposite direction.

***Triangle generator***

- OA2, C1, R4 and R1 form a triangle generator. When the input is high C1 starts to charge, driving the OA2 output negative to maintain the '-' input at the same potential as the '+' input.
- Since OA2 is fed back to the Schmitt trigger, at some point it will cause the trigger to toggle. This will start to reverse the charge direction in C1 and the output will rise linearly. Again, at a certain point the squarewave generator will toggle again.

The result is a triangle waveform which we can feed to the PWM generator.

***Voltage divider***

The PWM generator, LTC6992, accepts a 0 to 1 V signal to generate a 0 to 100% PWM signal. R7 and R8 divide the triangle signal down. You need to adjust these values depending on the output of OA2 which, in turn will depend on the supply voltage. Measure the peak value when you get the triangle generator running.

***PWM generator***

This is fairly straightforward and the datasheet is clear on its operation.

**Work for the OP**

- Triangle frequency calculations to be calculated. \$\tau = (R1 + R2)C \$ will give a good approximation.
- Schmitt trigger switching points to be calculated. Values given should work but may not be optimal.
- An opamp that can swing to negative rail will be required to get to 0% PWM.

**Further information**

- [Triangle wave generator](http://circuitswiring.com/triangular-wave-generator-circuit-2/).
- [LTC6992 datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/69921234fc.pdf).